# ExtJS 4.2.1 + Jax-RS get responseText

Tags: javascript, extjs, jax-rs

I use extjs framework version 4.2.1 + Jax-RS in my project

I'm trying to get response text and show it on UI:

Java code

```
@POST
@Path("/collections")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createCollection(@PathParam(PATH_PARAM_SITE_NAME) String siteName, @Context UriInfo uriInfo,
        CollectionBean collectionBean, @Context HttpRequest request) throws ParseException {


     ResponseBuilder rb = null;
     ...
     if (hasDeprecatedElements) {
        rb = Response.status(Status.FORBIDDEN);
        rb.entity(messageBuilder.toString());
        rb.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
        return rb.build();
    }
```

Then i try to handle this:

```
    failure:function(response, options){           
        if(403 === options.error.status){
             AlertUtils.showWarningAlert('collection.forbidden',response.responseText);
             saveButtonRef.setDisabled(false);
             saveButtonRef.setText("Save");
         }
      }
    });
```

And get the empty text window.

If i check response body in Chrome debugger i see that it contains message, but i can't see message in response object.

Comment: Should be noted that response object looks like ExtJS object which not contains responseText field. If i try to extract responseText in other cases i get it.